# FastApi and HTTP header Authorization: Token, get error in use "authorization: token is an invalid header name"

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, token, fastapi

I need use HTTP authorization with header Authorization: Token. My code:

```
@router.get('/versions',tags=["Credentials"],responses={
        200: {
            "model": List[models.versions_info],
            "description": "Return has code",
            "headers": {"Authorization": {"description":"Token party","type":"string"}}
        }})
async def list_versions(token: Union[str, None] = Header(description="Token party",alias="Authorization: Token",default=None)): 
    out=[{"version": "2.1.1","url": "https://www.server.com/ocpi/2.1.1/"},{"version": "2.2","url": "https://www.server.com/ocpi/2.2/"}]
    return Response(status_code=200,content=json.dumps(out), media_type="application/json", headers={"Authorization: Token "+config.globals["mytoken"]})
```

However, when using I get an error:

[image]

Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

Update: if i modify code to:

```
async def list_versions(token: Union[str, None] = Header(alias="Authorization",default=None))
```

the header is not sent at all:

[image]

Comment: The second `:` makes it so that it thinks the header is `Authorization: Token:`, not `Authorization` with `Token: 123` as its value. This may be a bug in swagger, since `:` is a valid character for a header's value.. It's also worth nothing that your documentation says that the field should be `Token 123`, without `:`.

Comment: updated the question a bit, please take a look